# Killing 'Fallen Lunatics' as a melee class

Tags: diablo-iii

[Fallen Lunatics](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Fallen_Lunatic) always seem to slay me when they explode. So is there any safe way to kill them as a melee class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ideas would be:

- Use skills with damage over time components, and run
- Use skills/runes that give you some range
- Use skills that give you temporary shields or invulnerability
- Have your follower kill them
- Run away!

As a Monk, I like to have some skill active that gives me some range, even if it's just Deadly Reach. Another option is Seven-Sided Strike, which effectively gives you a second of invincibility, but on a cooldown. Normally I play in groups so it's not a problem, but you have to be much more careful when solo!

Comment: Fists of Thunder/Thunderclap followed by Lashing Tail Kick/Sweeping Armada is very effective against these.  If the don't die they'll be knocked back quite far, and you can thunderclap right to them again to finish them off.

Answer (score 2):

Every melee class has some way of killing them. Barbarian can use Throw and the Monk can use Wave of light or Seven Sided Strike. There are many more. If you just need them out of the way however you can stand still a single second and then move away. They usually take a couple of seconds to explode. Thats the way I do it, or let my companion eat the damage.

Comment: Do you know some viable build which includes weapon throw? I would have a hard time incorporating it in my current build. And you can't respec, cause you will lose nephalem valour. I'm not in act 3 yet, but I can imagine I will have difficulties with them there, since they were quite dangerous already on hell difficulty, where I could get away with specing a ranged ability.

Comment: There are some quite interesting builds out there.

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/barbarian#fdQYXk!fWh!ZZaYbZ

or 

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149541682

As I havent been there on a barbarian I wouldnt know how effective they are.

On a side note though I would rather use Leap just before they explode. Requires some focus and timing.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this counts as a kill on your part, but with monks, you could cyclone strike them all on you, then followup with a serenity so that when they blow, you dont take any damage. Remember your cooldowns though!

Comment: As a monk this certainly is an easy way to kill them. Not sure if it gives any XP.

Comment: Exactly... BUT!!! If you DO cyclone strike them in, and it SHOULD count. I'll test later tonight as I am at work at the moment.